# Does VMWare Fusion 5.0.1 support Direct X 10?

Tags: vmware-fusion, directx

I just upgraded VMWare Fusion to 5.0.1 and I'm trying to find out if it supports DirectX 10. If not, will VMWare be bringing out an update soon?